# How can i pass a list of ids to "res_id" in javascript in odoo10?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I have a list of ids that i want to assign to res_id so that i can have multiple form views again my record in tree view. 
This is my code: ids is the list of ids that i have and want to assign to res_id.

```
//ids is the list of ids that i have
                    action_orig.res_id = self.mapped(ids);
                    action_orig.flags = {
                        form: {
                            pager : true,
                            "initial_mode": editable ? "edit" : "view",
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: not sure, if this is a question about programming, where's the relevant code? If it's just about using a web service, it's off-topic at SO, I guess. Also, you are expected to describe your attempts to solve the issue and how they failed. Best regards

Comment: Yes, thanks for viewing. I have edited it and uploaded the code @YakovL

Comment: well done! Looks like you've missed some closing brackets and it's not clear what `am` is, though.

Comment: Yes, Now i have mentioned it too. Kindly check and suggest the solution @YakovL

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not familiar with odoo, so can't easily help with questions about it and not JS itself, I can only help with writing your question better and more attractive. I think it's good that you shortened it considerably, but I suggest to keep expected and actual behaviour because assigning itself is done.. well, like any assinging in JS (I don't think the problem is about assigning really), although you may want to output `self.mapped(ids)` somewhere to check whether it contains what you expected; and may be some kind of view refreshing should be done

Comment: I have ids. I just need to pass them to res_id through domain filter in javascript.

Comment: Hi, 'res_id' with form view accept just one 'id' and don't support multi ids,

Comment: Thanks, So how can i show multiple forms on clicking on a treeview in dashboard. Basically in original treeview the pager is enabled and records can navigate but when i add it to my dashboard. The same treeview doesnt allow navigation. Can you suggest any solution? @KararaMohamed